# No of roots , using rmvt.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

If f(x) is differntiable function , such that fundamental period 
is 2. also f(0) is non zero. f has exactly two solutions
in [0,2]. To find minimum number of zeros of 
h(x) = f’(x) cos x -f(x) sin x in [0,99)

I wrote h(x) = (f(x)cos x)’.
now using Rolle theorem , i considered
k(x) = f(x) cos x .
so f(x) has atleast 98 roots in (0,99) , considering the roots in each period lie after the midpoint of interval.
also cos x has 32 solutions. so as whole k vanishes at 130 places. so dervative at 129 but answer is 127